# Reputation minus 2 and not showning Badge count when entering MSO

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

When I come to MSO, it shows my reputation 2 points lower than SO and the badge count is also not showing.

I understand badges from SO are not relevant to MSO, but why are the reputation points are reduced and shown at MSO?

Comment: Caching and batching. Always. Your numbers are not realtime-propagated to the rest of system. It's just not necessary, so it's batched once per hour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've already realised that badges earned on Stack Overflow don't carry over to Meta. You earn badges separately here.

As for the reputation - it's sync'd once an hour so at any time is going to be different. It'll catch up eventually.